# What does the Slurm status down* mean?

Tags: slurm

Last night, I successfully logged into a Slurm environment.  Today, I can't connect to the same environment.  The `sinfo` command is currently giving me the following:

```
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
p1           up 15-00:00:0      1   idle n1
p0*          up 15-00:00:0      1  down* n0
```

What does the status `down*` mean?

`sinfo -R` gives

```
REASON               USER      TIMESTAMP           NODELIST
Not responding       slurm     2023-07-08T03:37:34 n0
```

[Bard](https://bard.google.com/) says "down*" means the node is not responding to ping requests.

This makes sense, but I can't find documentation on this, and I'm a Slurm noob, so I wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bard is correct. See the first item in section https://slurm.schedmd.com/sinfo.html#SECTION_NODE-STATE-CODES of the `sinfo` manpage